# Using a javascript button to change html, with multiple values that are picked using an auto incrementing number

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Basic html:

```
<button id="changer">Changer button</button>
<div id="text"> </div>
```

"Changer" is the button element in html, "text" is the div tag in which our text will be placed.

```
var selector = 0;
```

We set the selector to 0. Next, every time the button "changer" is clicked, we add 1 to the selector var, unless it has reached its max value of 14, in which case we start over. And based on the selector value, we pick from the available text values.

```
document.getElementById("Changer").onclick = function () {
if (selector < 14) {
selector++;
}
else {
    selector = 0;
    selector++;
}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
}

if (selector = 1 ){
    text = "<p>this is text 1</p>";
if (selector = 2 ){
    text = "<p>this is text 2</p>";
etc...
```

The problem is, the function upon being clicked jumps right to the last text value available. How do I fix this? Will add live example soon if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are assigning the `selector` inside the `if` condition to a value.

```
if(selector = 1) {...
```

What you actually want to do is check if the `selectors` value is equal to something like so:

```
if(selector == 1) {...
```

But you do not need to repeat the check, you can simply do:

```js
var selector = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById('changer');
var output = document.getElementById('text');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (selector < 14) {
    selector++;
    output.innerHTML = "<p>this is text " + selector + "</p>";
  } else {
    selector = 0;
    output.innerHTML = "";
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="changer">Changer button</button>
<div id="text"> </div>
```